# Ice Age Glaciers Question

Tags: data-request, geospatial, historical

I am looking to find GIS data about the Ice age glacier's history around the Russia and Alaska area aka the Beringia Sea ...

Not sure how to find them but does anyone here have the information on that can I obtain the data?

Answer (score 2):

I found some promising hits from a Google search for "glacial extent shapefile bering sea," including:

- ArcGIS online layer (global extent): [Ice extent and coastline at the last glacial maximum](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f1e7378b962d42168fdefec3b6eb8b5f)
- [shapefiles of Pleistocene and Wisconsonian glacial extents in Alaska](http://instaar.colorado.edu/groups/QGISL/ak_paleoglacier_atlas/downloads/index.html)

A number of scientific articles also turned up during that search. If you look at those articles they may point you to more sources of data. If the article doesn't include a link to the data, you can always contact the author ask where they got their GIS data. Reputable scientific studies must be reproducible, which means that the source data should be available for other scientists, unless it's confidential. (Pre-historic glacial extent GIS data is unlikely to be confidential.)

Comment: Thank you i was able to open it and download with no problem.. Thank you !